# how to Add/Delete user on telegram channel using api

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

how to Add/Delete user on telegram channel using api

Can we do send message, add user or remove user using Rest API for telegram channel?

Comment: Maybe check the documentation? What have you tried or find out yourself so far?

Comment: Yes, check but did not found any way where we can add user or remove user from channesl using API.

Answer (score 0):

there is no REST API. there is only option ie SDK.